# Manipulating file content in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, security

I'm not a security expert. I'm working on a rails application where the user needs to upload a txt file to the app. The app doesn't store the file but reads its content and saves some of it in the database. Is it safe or not? If not is there a way to secure this like preventing the users from uploading txt files with malicious content?

Comment: Depends on what your database schema is.. assuming it's a string, you'll want to research escaping and sanitizing values..

Answer (score -1):

You're rightly concerned about the possibility of a so-called injection attack.

The Rails Guide "Securing Rails Applications" is very thorough and has a [section](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#injection) specifically on preventing various types of injection attacks.